# Conflicting upstream dependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have no idea what I need to do to get NPM install to run successfully after upgrading Node to 18.12.1 and npm to 9.2.0. I keep getting this upstream dependency error. I ran

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

And now this is where I am.

```
npm install                                                                                                                                                                            ─╯
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: hipersigno@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from react-svgmt@1.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-svgmt
npm ERR!   react-svgmt@"^1.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/mchildress/.npm/_logs/2023-01-09T16_27_29_875Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mchildress/.npm/_logs/2023-01-09T16_27_29_875Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: [Please post text, not links to images of text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: understood! Thanks. first time posting.

Answer (score 0):

What's going on is that react-svgmt has react 17 set as a peer dependency. This means that it is built only to support react 17. You have react 18 installed and npm sees that conflict and bails. You have the following options:

- Downgrade to React 17 by using `npm install --save react@^17.0.0 react-dom@^17.0.0`
- Indicate that you are okay with having a potentially incompatible version by using `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`.

Comment: Thank you so much! worked like a charm...led to a few more errors...but I just followed the same idea and everything is working again...I did have to run npx webpack init and remake the config file.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. If you find the answer acceptable, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: react-svgmt is updated to support React v18 now so you don't need to install legacy deps.